# Remove every line before a string in file using Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible, regexp-replace, ansible-bug

I have below file:

```
Scheduled jobs
Locale LANG set to the following: "en"
CONMAN:AWSBHU611W Conman could not initialize the HTTP or HTTPS connection.
Workstation Job Stream SchedTime Job State Pr Start Elapse ReturnCode Dependencies

HCPRODNWA #NW_HC_CA_BKP1 0106 02/13 **************************************** HOLD 10(02/13) (03:22)
NW_HC_CA_PREBKUP1B HOLD 10(02/13)(00:01)
NW_HC_CA_SANREPLICATION HOLD 10(02/13)(00:05)ΩNW_HC_CA_PREBKUP1B
NW_HC_CA_PPBACKUP HOLD 10(02/13)(03:17)
NW_HC_CA_SANREPLICATION
NW_HC_CA_GOLDCOPY HOLD 10(02/13)(00:01)
NW_HC_CA_SANREPLICATION
```

I want to remove all the lines before the line starting with 'Workstation Job...'

My ansible code is:

```
- name: Extract job details
  replace:
    path: /tmp/tws_jobs
    after: '(^Scheduled)'
    before: '(^Workstation)'
    regexp: '^(.*)$'
    replace: ''
```

But i'm not able to get the desired output. Instead i'm getting following message:

```
"msg": "Pattern for before/after params did not match the given file: (^Scheduled)(?P<subsection>.*?)(^Workstation)"
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `.` in regexp does not match the new line. Maybe try `regexp: '(.|\n)*'`

Comment: @Alex, I tried that, but it still gives the same message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```yaml
    after: '(^Scheduled)'
    before: '(^Workstation)'
```

Q: ***"Pattern for before/after params did not match the given file"***

**Update** (module *replace* explained)

Short answer: `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the file. Use `\n` to match the beginning and end of a line. The task below removes the lines between the lines *after* and *before*

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: /tmp/tws_jobs
        regexp: '.*'
        replace: ''
        after: '^Scheduled.*?\n'
        before: '\nWorkstation.*?\n'
```

running in *--check --diff* gives

```yaml
--- before: /tmp/tws_jobs
+++ after: /tmp/tws_jobs
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 Scheduled jobs
-Locale LANG set to the following: "en"
-CONMAN:AWSBHU611W Conman could not initialize the HTTP or HTTPS connection.
+
+
 Workstation Job Stream SchedTime Job State Pr Start Elapse ReturnCode Dependencies
```

Details:

The content of the file is [stored as a string](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/replace.py#L260)

```py
contents = to_text(f.read(), errors='surrogate_or_strict', encoding=encoding)
```

Given the file for testing

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt 
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

Declare the default parameters to simplify testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  module_defaults:
    replace:
      path: /tmp/test.txt
      regexp: '.*'
      replace: ''
  tasks:
    - replace:
        ...
```

1. Match the beginning of a file and line

- `^a` matches `a` at the beginning of the file
- `\n` starts a new line

```yaml
        after: '^a'
        before: '\nd'
```

gives

```yaml
-aaa
-bbb
-ccc
+a
+
+
 ddd
 eee
```

2. Match the rest of the line. In the previous example, the rest of the first line after `a` was removed. Match also the rest if you want to keep the whole line.

- [*after*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#parameter-after) and [*before*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#parameter-before) uses [*DOTALL*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) quote:

> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline

- Non-greedy `?` match all characters `.*` till the new line `\n`

```yaml
        after: '^a.*?\n'
        before: '\nd'
```

gives

```yaml
 aaa
-bbb
-ccc
+
+
 ddd
 eee
```

---

**Origin**

A: Neither *before* nor *after* pattern matches any line in the file. Correct patterns should be

```
    after: '^Scheduled(.*)$'
    before: '^Workstation(.*)$'
```

But these patterns don't work either probably because of the open issues [Replace module before/after still broken #47917](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/47917).

It's possible to test the various patterns in a simplified example

```
shell> cat test.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

The task

```
   - replace:
        path: test.txt
        after: 'bbb'
        before: 'ddd'
        regexp: '^(.*)$'
        replace: ''
```

works as expected

```
shell> cat test.txt
aaa
bbb

ddd
eee
```

But neither

```
   - replace:
        path: test.txt
        after: '^bb'
        before: '^dd'
        regexp: '^(.*)$'
        replace: ''
```

nor

```
   - replace:
        path: test.txt
        after: '^bb(.*)$'
        before: '^dd(.*)$'
        regexp: '^(.*)$'
        replace: ''
```

change anything in the file

```
PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1  changed=0  unreachable=0  failed=0  skipped=0  rescued=0  ignored=0
```

---

[1] https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/47917#issuecomment-686339762

Answer (score 0):

Try another approach: [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html#blockinfile-module):

```
- name: Extract job details
  blockinfile:
    marker_begin: '^Scheduled'
    marker_end: '^Workstation'
```